# Linux Unsupported proxy configured

Tags: linux, proxy, g++, debian

I'm new in linux, I just started using debian. I tried to install g++, by

```
apt-get install g++
```

but it didn't work

```
root@HP:/home/krzysztof# apt-get install g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  g++-6 libstdc++-6-dev
Suggested packages:
  g++-multilib g++-6-multilib gcc-6-doc libstdc++6-6-dbg libstdc++-6-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  g++ g++-6 libstdc++-6-dev
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,516 kB of archives.
After this operation, 39.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libstdc++-6-dev             amd64 6.3.0-18+deb9u1
  Unsupported proxy configured: 127.0.0.1://8888
Ign:2 http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 g++-6 amd64     6.3.0-18+deb9u1
Err:3 http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 g++ amd64 4:6.3.0-4
  Unsupported proxy configured: 127.0.0.1://8888
Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main     amd64 libstdc++-6-dev amd64 6.3.0-18+deb9u1
  Unsupported proxy configured: 127.0.0.1://8888
Err:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main     amd64 g++-6 amd64 6.3.0-18+deb9u1
  Unsupported proxy configured: 127.0.0.1://8888
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-    security/pool/updates/main/g/gcc-6/libstdc++-6-dev_6.3.0-18+deb9u1_amd64.deb          Unsupported proxy configured: 127.0.0.1://8888
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-    security/pool/updates/main/g/gcc-6/g++-6_6.3.0-18+deb9u1_amd64.deb      Unsupported proxy configured: 127.0.0.1://8888
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.pl.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-    defaults/g++_6.3.0-4_amd64.deb  Unsupported proxy configured:     127.0.0.1://8888
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --    fix-missing?
```

Comment: This question is off topic, and should be moved to SuperUser - https://superuser.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The error message says:

> Unsupported proxy configured: 127.0.0.1://8888

So it seems you (or somebody else) configured a bogus proxy server, it most likely should read `127.0.0.1:8888` (without the slashes (`//`).

You need to change these values either in your [`apt.conf(5)`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/apt.conf) (`/etc/apt/apt.conf` or `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`) or via the `http_proxy` environment variable.

Comment: i don't have apt.conf(5) file

Comment: `apt.conf(5)` is the usual way to direct you to the [manpage of apt.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/apt.conf) - i've updated the answer to include the link.

Comment: it wasnt me <3<3

Comment: the error message even says this if the proxy variable does not contain the slashes between name and port. The reason was the missing protocol specifier

Comment: See my answer below, posted last August, which is the correct one., This accepted answer is not correct

Answer (score 51):

The "//" is a clue that you have left the "http://" off the beginning of the proxy configuration

For example:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "127.0.0.1:8888/"
```

will give the error `Unsupported proxy configured: 127.0.0.1://8888`, whereas

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8888/"
```

will correctly set the proxy

Comment: Hi, where is it, some conf file?

Comment: @PeterKrauss the file is `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, you can create it if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Create file /etc/apt/apt.conf and add following content:

```
 "http://<IP>:<PORT>/";
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the environment variables set for `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`.

Inspect them here:

```
echo $http_proxy
echo $https_proxy
```

And unset them afterwards:

```
unset $http_proxy
unset $https_proxy
```